# How to add caption while upload video on Facebook using the 3.0 version of the SDK.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm using the 3.0 version of the SDK for upload video on Facebook from android   there's a helper method that uploads videos Doc link is :- 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Request#newUploadVideoRequest(Session,%20File,%20Callback)

Problem is that i didn't add Caption of the video. So how could i add caption for the video ???

Answer (score 0):

See the videos doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#videos

You can set the "title" and "description" parameters, like this:

```
Request request = Request.newUploadVideoRequest(...);
Bundle params = request.getParameters();
params.putString("title", "Your Title Here");
request.setParameters(params);
request.executeAsync();
```